# Прием TCP пакета на PHP

Tags: php, c#, tcp-ip

Отправляю TCP пакет из программы на C#

```
        string IP = "127.0.0.1";
        string Port = "8000";        

        // инициализация сокета
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        // создание параметра для подключения к серверу
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(ip, int.Parse(Port));
        EndPoint end = (EndPoint)ipe;
        try
        {
            socket.Connect(ipe);
        }
        catch(SocketException ex) // на случай каких-либо проблем
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Проблемы с установкой соединения.\nПриложение будет закрыто."+ ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.Exit();
        }

        string str = "привет андрей hello andry 1245";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
        socket.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, 0);
```

Как мне получить сообщение "привет андрей hello andry 1245" на php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я плохо знаю C#, но я знаю PHP. 
Сначала создать на PHP сокет.

```js
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) < 0) {
echo "Ошибка создания сокета";
}
```

Дальше привять Ip, и port, ибо я так понял ваш код, это клиент.

```js
if (($ret = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port)) < 0) {//в $addres помести адрес, которому делаешь запрос с C#, и в порт засунь тот же порт что в C#.
echo "Ошибка связи сокета с адресом и портом";
}
```

Потом слушаем сокет, получаем сообщения

```js
//Начинаем прослушивание сокета (максимум 5 одновременных соединений)
  if (($ret = socket_listen($sock, 5)) < 0) {
    echo "Ошибка при попытке прослушивания сокета";
  }
  else {
    echo "Ждём подключение клиента\n";
  }
  do {
    //Принимаем соединение с сокетом
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) < 0) {
      echo "Ошибка при старте соединений с сокетом";
    } else {
      echo "Сокет готов к приёму сообщений\n";
    }
    //Бесконечный цикл ожидания клиентов
    do {
      echo 'Сообщение от клиента: ';
      if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 1024))) {
        echo "Ошибка при чтении сообщения от клиента";       }
      else {
        echo $buf."\n"; //Сообщение от клиента
      }
    } while (true);
  } while (true);
```

Подробнее про сокеты, почитайте тут - http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sockets.php, так же вот клиент серверная архитектура, вам просто надо повторить клиент на C#, сервер будет работать независимо от клиента. Клиент - https://myrusakov.ru/php-socket-client.html, сервер https://myrusakov.ru/php-socket-server.html

UPD: выполнить этот скрипт, можно через CLI. Чтобы выполнить скрипт через CLI(командую строку), вам надо установить PHP с оф сайта, распаковать его в папку.
И сообственно создать файл с <<кодом>>. После чего в командой строк, вы вводите — путь к папке с php от самого диска\php.exe путь_к_файлу_с_кодом\index.php

Это самый просто способ запуска скрипта по CLI.

Comment: Допустим я запишу этот код в index.php, каким образом скрипт будет постоянно слушать порт если сам index.php никто не вызывает ? Нужно добавить cron задачу ?

Comment: Можно добавить крон, можно запустить с помощью CLI. Второй вариант лучше.

Comment: Точнее, нет, крон здесь не уместен, во-первых как вы получите сообщение? Во-вторых, сокет listen и do while, конструкция котороя останавливает выполнения. Так что лучше выполни через CLI, как, я сейчас отредактирую ответ.

Comment: На локальном хосте скрипт находится на данном этапе, в концовке все равно все будет установлено на vps/хостинг.

Comment: Тогда, при запросе на сервер тот по идее не будет отвечать, дотех пор, пока мы не получим сообщения, ? Не закроем соединение. Пробуйте, я лишь показал как получить сообщение. Кстати, в конце кода, уже после do while, надо поместить `socket_close(сюда имя сокета);`.

Comment: Скрипт на сервере должен быть в постоянном ожидании сообщения от программы, как только сообщение получено, сервер его обрабатывает и дает ответ, после чего опять переходит в режим ожидания. Так же не совсем понятно что если нужно передать информацию больше чем 1024 бит информации.

Comment: Скрипт вы просто один раз запускаете из браузера,  потом зачисляете его игнорировать пользователя, и все, он будет работать, но задача у вас не травильная, вы пытаетесь написать демона на PHP. А 1024 бита данных, просто указал я, вы можете поставить больше. Игнорирования отключения пользователя(скрипт прийдется один раз вызвать) — [http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Comment: Вот интрумктя по созданию демона на PHP [https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/134620/](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/134620/)